# xampp installed in ubuntu but php and mysql shows not found

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.4

I have installed XAMPP version 7.4 in UBUNTU OS,

now when I go to the terminal and type **php -v** command,

it shows

```
root@roy:/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento242# php -v

Command 'php' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install php7.4-cli
```

also when i type **mysql -u root -p** it shows like below,

```
root@roy:/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento242# sudo mysql -u root -p
sudo: mysql: command not found
root@roy:/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento242# mysql -u root -p

Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, or
apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
```

I don't understand that what is the problem exactly.

but when I run localhost/phpmyadmin then phpmyadmin is open.
so what is the problem with that?

please provide me some suggestions on that,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start Lampp first then mysql. Follow these steps:

1. Open up terminal using CTRL+ALT+T
2. type

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

3.Switch to the XAMPP installation directory. Type in

`cd /opt/lampp`

4.Then you just need to type this command in order to run lampp properly

```
sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run
```

if you need to use mysql in terminal do the next step

5.cd /opt/lampp/bin

```
./mysql -u root
```

Answer (score 0):

To access XAMPP bundles such as php globally, I did the following;

- Add `lampp` bin directory to PATH: Open `~/.bashrc` with an editor of your choice, and add the line `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin"`
- then perform symlink for php as follows `sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php`

PHP is now accessible. Test with `php -v` and you should get the installed PHP details